# Bootstrap image and text side by side in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put an image and texts side by side in bootstrap inside a single div.. For that I used the `class` of `thumbnail`. But using bootstrap thumbnail it makes the image to go at the top and all the texts at the bottom.

So I changed it a bit to put the image and the texts within the thumbnail only and dividing the thumbnail into two parts. But on resizing the screen into small the problem is arising.. The texts are shifting over the image..

Here is the code of what I tried till now

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">

              <div class="thumbnail" style="border:none; background:white; height:210px;">

              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <img src="images/online_learning.jpg" style="height:200px; margin-left:-15px;" />
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">  

                <h3>Hello World</h3>
                 <p style="font-size:10px; color:#03225C;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit adipiscing blandit. Aliquam placerat, velit a fermentum fermentum, mi felis vehicula justo, a dapibus quam augue non massa.   </p>
              </div>
              </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot without resizing](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=dvhmwy&s=8#.VMiAc993M8o)

[Screenshot after resizing](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=21bsnqr&s=8#.VMiByd93M8o)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">

              <div class="thumbnail" style="border:none; background:white;">

              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 image-container">
                <img src="images/online_learning.jpg" style="height:200px; margin-left:-15px;" />
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">  

                <h3>Hello World</h3>
                 <p style="font-size:10px; color:#03225C;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit adipiscing blandit. Aliquam placerat, velit a fermentum fermentum, mi felis vehicula justo, a dapibus quam augue non massa.   </p>
              </div>
              </div>

 </div>
```

css code write this in media query if u need only for mobile

```
.image-container{text-align:center}
```

in case if u need both the image and text side by side in mobile device,
remove the height for the image in media query to mobile devices resolution, give width 100% to the image

Comment: In this case after resizing the texts move to the bottom of the image but without the `background of white`. Only the image gets the white background behind it but the texts don't have that white background after resizing. Try it and tell me..

Comment: since we given float property we need to clear it  use this CSS .thumbnail{clear:both;float:none;}

Comment: could u try this pls  .thumbnail:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }                  add this CSS

Comment: ahh.. it worked.. :) but on resizing how can i put the image on the center of the div.? it's inclined towards left..

Comment: add text-align:center  to image parent div.  vote up if ur satisfied

Comment: yeah i will .. you edit your answer first.. and can you please tell me about middling the image on resizing.. ?

Comment: check in above code i have  added a class image container and written a css for it  class name is "image-container"

Answer (score 9):

You need to make sure you're using div's with the class of `row` around your columns, also if you're going to have col-xs-6 it sets this columns size (6) on the larger sizes too (no need to use col-sm-6 etc also).

Try this code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  
 <div class="row" style="border:none; background:white; height:210px;">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <img src="images/online_learning.jpg" style="height:200px; margin-left:-15px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">  
   <h3>Hello World</h3>
   <p style="font-size:10px; color:#03225C;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit adipiscing blandit. Aliquam placerat, velit a fermentum fermentum, mi felis vehicula justo, a dapibus quam augue non massa.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I have used `class row`. I edited my code.. But in your code too the texts and the image are colliding.. And you didn't properly read my question.. I included both the image and div inside a `thumbnail class`

Comment: Make sure you place a row around every set of columns as well. (include it within or on the thumbnail div. The issue when using the thumbnail class in this instance is that it is not made for this exact use and thus it might break as it is. Thus creating something similar with other classes might be a better option (using styled divs with the class of "well"). If you still need any help I can try re-create it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This question is still a valid requirement for many use cases, hence answering this question with the latest bootstrap features. Using bootstrap flex properties, the image and text can be easily displayed in parallel

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Learning Websites</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/isolated-happy-smiling-dog-white-background-portrait-4_1562-693.jpg" class="img-thumbnail w-75 h-75 align-self-center border-0">
                <div class="align-items-center">
                    <p class="h3">Cute Dog</p>
                    <p style="font-size:10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit adipiscing blandit. Aliquam placerat, velit a fermentum fermentum, mi felis vehicula justo, a dapibus quam augue non massa.   </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/isolated-happy-smiling-dog-white-background-portrait-4_1562-693.jpg" class="img-thumbnail w-75 h-75 align-self-center border-0">
                <div class="align-items-center">
                    <p class="h3">Cute Dog</p>
                    <p style="font-size:10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit adipiscing blandit. Aliquam placerat, velit a fermentum fermentum, mi felis vehicula justo, a dapibus quam augue non massa.   </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


 </body>
```